# Javascript Function Not Accessible when Dynamically Writing a Script

Tags: javascript, document.write

so I have an external javascript file, lets call it `something.js` and i document.write it to the document.  For some reason, I cant access the function in Safari or FireFox.

It goes a little something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.write(decodeURI("%3Cscript src='something.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
    myFunction();
</script>
```

so this tells me myFunction is null, but if i put that same function call at the end of something.js, it works.  Now this isnt the exact scenario, so I am aware that for this particualr case, this is not the best way to go about it.

Comment: Does it work when you embed the script directly using `<script src="..."> ?

Comment: yes, but for this particular case, i need to do a document.write

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how I do it:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language='javascript'>
  document.write('<script type="text/javascript" id="contentloadtag" defer="defer" src="something.js"><\/script>');
  var contentloadtag=document.getElementById("contentloadtag");
  contentloadtag.onreadystatechange=function(){
    if (this.readyState=="complete") { myFunction(); }
  }
</script>
```

Really, this makes sense only at page load time.  If you are repeatedly downloading script in a dynamic fashion, you probably want to take a different approach, namely JSONP.

Comment: This is better than accepted answer because you can not guarantee that any fixed amount of seconds is enough for a script to load.

Comment: this works great and seems much more solid than checking every 2 seconds

Answer (score 2):

I think this happens because  `myFunction();` is called before the whole .js file that contains it loaded in the browser, try to delay  `myFunction();` call few seconds and test again to make sure that this is the problem.

Comment: if i delay it for 2 seconds, will it delay my page from loading for 2 seconds?

Comment: yes specially if this script code exists in the beginning of your page code

Comment: then that really isnt a viable solution as i cannot keep the page form loading.

Comment: You can use a settimeout javascript function and call the function again after few seconds if the previous call failed

Comment: or check if a variable inside the .js filed got a value and not = undefined

Answer (score 0):

After you print the script inclusion tag using document.write the browser continues execution (trying to invoke `myFunction()`) before it loads external script. So, your script is not available yet.

Answer (score 0):

1. Put your dynamic `script` block in the
   `head` of your document (if it isn't
   already)
2. Remove the `myFunction()` call.
3. Put `myFunction()` call in a different
   `script` block somewhere lower on
   the document.

*Step 1 is a best practice, but I don't think any browser will choke if you dynamically include the JS file at some other point in the document.*

**The key point is that you can't make use of included JS code from within the same script block that does the inclusion.**

This works in Firefox, I can't vouch for Safari.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            document.write(decodeURI("%3Cscript src='something.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            myFunction();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

*I wouldn't normally write two separate answers, but this a very different answer, that's just as likely to work.*

Put a call to `something_ready()` at the bottom of something.js.  Don't define `something_ready()` in something.js, define it in your html document.

So no timers, no unneeded checking.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.write(decodeURI("%3Cscript src='something.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));

        function something_ready(){
            myFunction();
        }
    </script>
```

That will work, it just assumes that you have access to something.js, which you may not.  If not, the other answer I provided will work.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='something.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
document.write("<"+"script type='text/javascript>myFunction();<"+"/script>");
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to write two <script> blocks.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.write(decodeURI("%3Cscript src='something.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    myFunction();
</script>
```

When **document.write** is used, the text is written directly into the document, right after the <script> tag. Because of this, when a browser encounters a <script> tag, it waits for the script to finish loading before continuing down the page. Any **document.write** that happens in the loaded script might affect the rest of the page (for example, if you do "document.write('<div>')", it will affect the rest of the layout).

So, if you use two <script> tags, the first one is encountered by the browser, and it uses **document.write** to output a new <script> tag. As soon as that <script> tag is finished, the browser continues down the page, and immediately encounters the new, dynamically added <script> tag. This <script> tag tells the browser to load your external Javascript. The browser will wait to execute the second original <script> tag until this <script> tag has finished loading. Then your function **myFunction** will be available.

The reason doing it all in one <script> tag doesn't work is because **document.write** doesn't happen until after the <script> has finished running (**myFunction** isn't available yet). The reason it works with two <script> tags is because the browser waits until each <script> tag runs in succession, and **document.write** puts a new <script> tag in line.